# Carousel Indicators not working on Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was trying to make a carousel of 8 images however the indicators are not working neither are the left and right arrows. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel1" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#i1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#i2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#i3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#i4" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#i5" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#i6" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    <li data-target="#i7" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    <li data-target="#i8" data-slide-to="7"></li>
  </ol>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have the actual slides in there, do you know that?
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I have include the bootstrap files. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The whole `carousel-inner` (which is where the slides themselves are located) is missing. Of course it's not going to work. Honsa Stunna already provided an answer with the elements that are missing.

Answer (score 2):

The data-target has to be the carousel selector, in your case the element id myCarousel.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>.item {
  height: 100px;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}</style>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel1" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```